# LINQ equivalent of the following code?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm in the process of learning LINQ and would like some help the following method.  How can I rewrite the following method to use LINQ?

```
private bool IsInList(string file, List<FileInfo> excelList)
{
    if (excelList != null && excelList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo f in excelList)
        {
            if (string.Compare(f.FullName, file, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd change the second parameter to accept an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` instead so you're not limiting yourself to just lists.

```
private bool IsInList(string file, IEnumerable<FileInfo> excelList)
{
    return excelList != null && excelList.Any(f => f.FullName.Equals(file, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: Technically this is not equivalent: Your code could throw an exception where the original one would not - when `FullName` is null.

Comment: Thank you, I like the one liner.  For some reason I was trying to do it with Where().  I'm just jumping into LINQ, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @Chris: I've thought about that and came to the conclusion that the `FullName` would never be `null`.  I'm pretty sure that is the case.  There's no logical reason to me why they'd make it return `null` in any case.  Otherwise, it would be a simple fix to use the static equality comparer.

Answer (score 3):

Using lambdas:

```
private bool IsInList(string file, List<FileInfo> excelList)
{
    return excelList != null && excelList.Any(f => string.Compare(f.FullName, file, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
}
```

Comment: Might be that you're throwing an exception where he was not throwing one before. He was asking for an *equivalent.*

Comment: Wasn't my downvote however: You have changed the semantics of the code without any obvious reason (throwing an exception)

Comment: I'll upvote ya.  A null check in this case is not necessarily a bad thing.  If this is indeed the reason for the downvote, then it is misplaced, even if it isn't a literal translation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
private bool IsInList(string file, List<FileInfo> excelList)
{
    if (excelList == null) return false;
    return excelList.Any(f => string.Compare(f.FullName, file, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try -- completely untested.

```
private bool IsInList(string file, List<FileInfo> excelList)
{
    if (excelList != null && excelList.Count > 0)
    {
        return excelList.Any(f => string.Compare(f.FullName, file, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do...

```
if (excelList != null && excelList.Count > 0)
{
    return (from f in excelList
            where (string.Compare(f.FullName, file, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            select f).Any();
}
return false;
```